# What is the maximum height of a Btree as a function of n?

Tags: algorithm, tree

I have the following problem:

> For a B-tree of degree 1, what is the maximum height for a the tree as
>   a function of the number of keys n in the tree?

And I thought that because the order of the tree is 1 that means the number of keys can be between 1 and 2. Therefore I took a tree with only 1 key in each node so I can have the maximum height. Adding the number of nodes for each  level I got that

2^0+2^1+2^2+...+2^h= n, where n is the number of nodes and h is the height of the tree
and solving it I got that the height h is log(n+1) but I'm not really sure this is the right answer.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Height of  binary tree `h=log(n+1)-1`

Here is the derivation

Here i am assuming height of root is zero

so

```
n=2^0+2^1+2^2........2^h
```

Apply Geometric progression formula & get

```
h=log(n+1)-1.
```

Here log base is 2.
So when there is only single node at every level. We can  get log(2)base 2, n times SO  Maximum height becomes

```
h=n-1
```

Answer (score 0):

The worst case height for a B-Tree of order m is logm/2n.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Best_case_and_worst_case_heights